# Structure Map - Inject Collection of Named Instances

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

This question is very similar to a question I have previously asked (and had answered): [Structure Map - Collection of Dependencies in Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32199513/structure-map-collection-of-dependencies-in-constructor)

In my registry I have the following:

```
For<IMyObject>().Add<MyObjectType1>().Named("Type1");
For<IMyObject>().Add<MyObjectType2>().Named("Type2");
For<IMyObject>().Add<MyObjectType3>().Named("Type3");
```

I would like to inject all instances into a constructor, such that I may retrieve any named instance.  Example code (produces StructureMap exception):

```
public class Example
{
  private Dictionary<string, IMyObject> _workers;

  public Example(Dictionary<string, IMyObject> workers)
  {
    _workers = workers;
  }

  public void DoSomeStuff(string mode)
  {
     var worker = _workers[mode];
     worker.DoStuff();
  }
}
```

My reasoning for this approach is to allow external configuration to specify how something should be dealt with (in above example 'mode' would correspond to a named instance).

The actual exception is as follows:

```
StructureMap.StructureMapException occurred
  ErrorCode=202
  HResult=-2146232832
  Message=StructureMap Exception Code:  202
No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily
```

I am aware that I can use the StructureMap container in my method DoSomeStuff in order to retrieve a named instance, however, this is something of an anti-pattern.

So to clarify my question:

- Can I inject a dictionary (or other collection) of named instances, such that I can refer to them by name?

Hopefully this is clear, please comment back if further explanation is required.

- C#: 4.0
- StructureMap: 2.5.4.0

Thanks,

Graeme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of injecting a dictionary, it might be better to inject a `Func<string, IMyObject>` instead. This prevents StructureMap from having to create all `IMyObject` instances with all their dependencies, while only one of them really needs to be used:

```
public class Example
{
  private Func<string, IMyObject> _workers;
  public Example(Func<string, IMyObject> workers)
  {
    _workers = workers;
  }

  public void DoSomeStuff(string mode) => _workers(mode).DoStuff();
}
```

You can register your `Example` as follows:

```
For<Example>()
    .Use(() => new Example(mode => container.GetInstance<IMyObject>(instanceKey: mode)));
```

Comment: Thanks @Steven for taking time to respond.  A single instance of Example will usee all instanes of IMyObject at some point, through repeated calls.  The example class is mainly responsible for directing to the correct implementation of IMyObject.  I know I could 'new up' a dictionary in the registry when Example calss gets requested, but hoping there is a more elegant solution

Comment: @GinjaNinja: I find the solution presented the most elegant. Why isn't this solution working for you?

Comment: Apologies, I may have been a bit quick off the mark there.  Your solution does work for me and I shall accept the answer.  I had been hoping that there was a built in way to get all instances presented in some kind of collection, without the additional 'wire up' of the example class.  As a side question, are you aware of a way to ensure that only a single object of each implementation of IMyObject is created?

Comment: @GinjaNinja: `For<IMyObject>().Add<MyObjectType1>().Named("Type1").Singleton();`.

Comment: Close:
For<IMyObject>().Singlet‌​on().Add<MyObjectType1>().Named("Type1");

Comment: You can use this approach for factory pattern or conditional construction via structure map